# Filtering out values inside the field using SQL command

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table as below:
[image: Table 1]
And I have another table as below:

[image: Table 2]
Now, I want to filter out the image name from table 1-image description field and compare it with image name in the table 2 and return the image ID in the output table. So I want my output table like below:

[image: Output table]
Could someone please help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using Oracle and not MySql, so try this query with a `left` join of table1 to table2 and the operator `like`:

```
select t1.Name, t2."image id"
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
on t1."image description" like '%image="' || t2.image || '" />'
```

This will work for the sample data as you posted it, but if `image="..."` may appear anywhere inside the string then use:

```
on t1."image description" like '%image="' || t2.image || '"%'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=68302bc282f486a9b81814abeee42c89).
Results:

```
> NAME | image id
> :--- | -------:
> x    |        1
> b    |     null
> y    |        2
> z    |        2
> a    |     null
```

Comment: I wanna understand last part of your query: like '%image="' || t2.image || '" />'. Could u please explain me?

Comment: It concatenates the static string `image=` with t2.image to return something like `%image="xxx"%`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `substring_index()`.  Assuming it is the last value:

```
select substring_index(image_description, 'image=', -1)
from t;
```

If it can be anywhere in a semicolon separated list:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(image_description, 'image=', -1), ';', 1)
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=43e223395be2155fde44053790044413) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

In Oracle, you would simply use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(image_description, '^.*image=([^;]+).*', '\1')
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a7aa2448b8cc4e12d6325e17bb82945a) is a db<>fiddle for this version.

The rest is simply joining on the values.

Comment: I'm not sure why Im getting same error for all these commands !! ORA-00904: "SUBSTRING_INDEX": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: @Dora . . . Because you tagged the question MySQL and are using Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

if your image description content pattern is always  the same  and the value youa are looking for is at the right od the `=` char

then you could check for the right part after the = char this way

For mysql

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(your_column_name,'=',-1) 
from your_table 
where your_column_name like '%image%';
```

for Oracle you could use

SUBSTR(youc_col, INSTR(you_col, '=') + 1)

```
select SUBSTR(youc_col, INSTR(you_col, '=') + 1) 
from your_table 
where your_column_name like '%image%';
```

Comment: Im getting locate invalid identified error. I tried with position also but still its not working

Comment: be sure you are using the proper column name

Comment: yes its correct but I'm still getting that error :( Not sure why

Comment: show me the exact error message text ..  please ... i'm not using locate  ..so be sure you are using my code

Comment: This is error message Im getting - ORA-00904: "SUBSTRING_INDEX": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Sorry. I have added oracle tag now.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values for column image_desc has always the same format that ends with the text pattern `image=....`, the following would work.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(image_desc, LOCATE('image=', image_desc) + 6) AS image
FROM images;
```

Comment: Im getting Locate invalid identifier error. I tried with position() function also but it's not working.